# How to findout a number between two column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Suppose I have table called `dbo.tbl_Search`

```
Id    From    To
-------------------
1     200     210
2     212     220
3     203     215
4     225     240
```

Suppose, I search for `No.-205` then I would to like result like this

```
Id    From    To
-------------------
1     200     210
3     203     215
```

Because `205 No.` falls between this two ids.

**Note**: I don't have any other table  to join with this.

I have tried this SQL but it's bot working:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tbl_Search 
WHERE 
    (ISNULL(From, 0) = (CASE WHEN ISNULL(205, 0) = 0 
                                THEN ISNULL(From, 0) 
                                ELSE ISNULL(205, 0) 
                        END ) 
    OR ISNULL(To, 0) = (CASE WHEN ISNULL(205, 0) = 0 
                                THEN ISNULL(To, 0) 
                                ELSE ISNULL(205, 0) 
                        END ))
```

Comment: `where seasrched_number between from and to`. Maybe add `or searchednumber is null`

Comment: Isn't this just a between, or a >=from and <=To. Your description does not mention anything about the values being null.

Comment: @@dnoeth thank u sir....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tbl_Search 
WHERE ISNULL(@number, 0) BETWEEN FROM AND TO
```

Using between operator you can find a records between range.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand this correctly but shouldn't a simple query like below work

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tbl_Search 
WHERE From >= 205 AND To <= 205
```

Comment: This seems like the simplest answer.

Answer (score 0):

It should be simple number comparison as per your question.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_Search
WHERE FROM <= 205 AND TO >= 205
```